# Re-install working version of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have an Asus laptop that I got over the summer which came with Windows 8. I installed Ubuntu so I could dual-boot, but something happened (I cannot say what it was, for I really don't know) and I have not been able to boot into Ubuntu since. Because of this, I deleted the Ubuntu partition, and then tried booting from my Windows 8 recovery USB. When I tried this, I followed instructions that said I would have to use the command prompt to write in `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. Doing this was supposed to delete the rest of Ubuntu that was left on my computer after I deleted the partition.

However, I restarted my computer after entering that into the command prompt, and the bootloader brought up the option to boot into Ubuntu. Still!

Now, I don't know if this matters or not, but I want to get rid of Ubuntu and replace it with a version that isn't missing components or what have you, so that way I can use it again. Because, as we know, Windows 8 is the worst!

I tried looking through old answers to see if there was something that could help me, but so far, everything I've read has been the same thing. Is there anyone out there that might be able to help me? I just want to eliminate the old, broken version, and reinstall a new, working version.

Comment: @psusi: The actual question is in the last paragraph and the title was misleading (that's why I changed it). Therefore I don't find this question to be a duplicate of the one mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, ahh, in that case it's just a bad/unclear question... if you want to reinstall ubuntu, then.. reinstall ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

1. You can **re-install Ubuntu** the same way, you installed it the first time. Format or delete the partitions assigned to the previous installation, to make sure, it's gone and doesn't mess with the new installation. You can use the partition manager built-in to the installation assistant with the [*Something else*](/q/163962/175814) option.

   You can keep using Windows, while Ubuntu is installed, if you don't find it reliable enough (yet). Alternatively, you can choose to “Try Ubuntu” without installation to check out hardware compatibility (see next point).
2. **Hardware compatibility** is a big issue on Linux unfortunately for various reasons. If a piece of hardware isn't brand new¹ or exotic, there are actually good chances, that it runs out of the box or with a few simple touches.

   In many cases though, drivers need to be installed manually or even compiled from source. Often you'll [find a relevant question](/search) here.

   In all other cases you can [ask your own question](/questions/ask) and people will try to help you, if they know how (which usually comes down to searching online for suitable descriptions and instructions and adapting them to the specifics of Ubuntu). To speed things up, it helps if you follow the advice on asking hardware compatibility questions:

   - [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](/q/14008/175814)
   - [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](/q/425155/175814)
3. If you hardware is **very old and/or underpowered** (e. g. in the case of netbooks), take a look at [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814).

¹ compared to the kernel used by a particular Ubuntu release